# How to change the colour of a selected WPF DataGrid row header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid whose row headers get filled with (a small amount of) text, and this works great... until you highlight the row, when the text turns white and is barely visible:

[image]

In an attempt to force it to stay black, I set the following code containing both an `IsSelected` trigger and an explicit `DataTemplate` with its colour also set.

```xml
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Unfortunately, neither of these has any effect. The text remains stubbornly white until the row is deselected.

How can I force this text to remain black (or any other colour) when selected?

Comment: try moving the trigger into the template

Comment: Do it also for the cell style

Comment: @Steve That did the trick! I think I was thinking outside the box (or, er, XAML element) a bit much. If you post that as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style trigger is defined on the row itself instead of the header's template item. Simply move the trigger definition into the header template would do the trick.